# In pycharm, how do you insert documentation comments for the whole file

Tags: python, pycharm

In phpstorm you just press `cmd + N` and there is an option to Generate PHPDoc blocks for all methods in the file and it automatically takes into account type hinting.

so:

```
function(param1:str): array {
```

will automatically have in docstring

```
@param1:str
@return:array
```

I cannot find how to do this in pycharm, instead I have to go through each method and do it individually and the docstring don't have the type automatically inserted.